# VirtualBox: Mini toolbar can't be placed on top of screen

Tags: virtualbox

I want to place Mini Toolbar at top of screen.

I'm looking for this setting:

[image]

But is missing on VirtualBox Version 5.0.14 r105127:
[image]

My Host OS is Windows 7. My Guest OS is Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2):

In later versions of VirtualBox, the Mini Toolbar settings are located under "User Interface," instead of "General."

To access the Mini Toolbar settings, select your virtual machine in VirtualBox, select the machine's settings, then select User Interface.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have already checked the mini toolbar option and yet in the scaled mode you're not able to see the top and bottom mini toolbar, just press **L Crtl + C**